# The vector $\mid \phi \rangle \langle \phi \mid \psi \rangle$ is the projection of a vector $\mid \psi \rangle$ along the vector $\mid \phi \rangle$?

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, physics, inner-products, quantum-mechanics

I am currently studying the textbook *Mathematical methods of quantum optics* by Ravinder R. Puri. When going over some basic facts associated with bra-ket notation, the author says the following:

> The vector $\mid \phi \rangle \langle \phi \mid \psi \rangle$ is the *projection* of a vector $\mid \psi \rangle$ along the vector $\mid \phi \rangle$.

I'm unsure of this. The scalar product $\langle \phi \mid \psi \rangle$ is a measure of the overlap between the vectors $\mid \psi \rangle$ and $\mid \phi \rangle$. So how is it then the case that $\mid \phi \rangle \langle \phi \mid \psi \rangle$ is the *projection* of a vector $\mid \psi \rangle$ along the vector $\mid \phi \rangle$? I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to explain this.

Comment: Presumably, both vectors have length $1$, right? I.e. $\langle\phi\mid\phi\rangle=\langle\psi\mid\psi\rangle=1$.

Comment: @Arthur yes, that's always assumed in quantum mechanics.

Comment: @Arthur $\mid \phi \rangle$ is a unit vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already on the right track

> The scalar product $\langle \phi | \psi \rangle$ is a measure of the overlap between the vectors $| \psi \rangle$ and $| \phi \rangle$

Indeed, and *overlap* can also be read as *projection*, this is just a simple inner product of two vectors. And you know that is the way of [getting a projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection): via the inner product.

Now if you multiply that scalar times the vector $|\phi \rangle$ you will get the projection along $|\phi \rangle$

Comment: Because, as Arthur mentioned in the comments, $\mid \phi \rangle$ is a unit vector?

Comment: @ThePointer Correct, look at the section `Vector Projection` on the wiki-link above, there should be a $\langle \phi | \phi \rangle$ in the denominator, but you're assuming these vectors are normalized

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. An isolated quantum system is described by a vector in a Hilbert space. Two vectors differing only by a multiplying constant represent the same physical state.